# In Unity, why won't the speed change when I'm crouching?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform trnsform;

    public float JumpH = 3f;

    //these are the speed variables (which are the variables that are the problem)
    public float Speed = 20f;
    public float AirSpeed = 10;

    // this is to check if the player is on the ground
    public LayerMask Groundmask;
    public Transform groundcheck;
    bool isGrounded;
    public float GroundDistance = 0.4f;

    bool isCrouching = false;

    Vector3 Velocity;
    public float Gravity = -9.81f;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //this is the movement
        float X = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float Z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 move = transform.right * X + transform.forward * Z;
        Velocity.y += Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(Velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        controller.Move(move * Speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //this defines what needs to be met for isGrounded to be true
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundcheck.position, GroundDistance, Groundmask);

        //this resets the players downward velocity when they're on the ground
        if(isGrounded == true  && Velocity.y < 0) 
        {
            Velocity.y = -2f;
        }
        
        //this controls jumping
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded && !isCrouching) 
        {
            Velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(JumpH * -2f * Gravity);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
            {
                Velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(1.5f * -2f * Gravity);

            }
        }

        //this is the code that isn't working
        if(isCrouching)
        {
            Speed = 10f;
        }
        else
        {
            Speed = 20f;
        }

        //this makes the player crouch
        if(Input.GetKey("left ctrl")) 
        {
            
            trnsform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 0.5f, 1f);
            isCrouching = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            trnsform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
            isCrouching = false;
        }

        //this makes the player move slower while in air
        if (isGrounded == false)
        {
            Speed = AirSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            Speed = 20; 
        }

    }

    //this makes the player bounce when they hit anyting tagged with bounce
    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        if(hit.collider.tag == "Bounce") 
        {
            Velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(9f * -2f * Gravity);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of your Update method, you have this block:

```
    if (isGrounded == false)
    {
        Speed = AirSpeed;
    }
    else
    {
        Speed = 20; 
    }
```

That means that after this block, `Speed` will be either `AirSpeed` or `20`. The stuff you are doing further above based on the value of `isCrouching` is irrelevant, because it gets overwritten before the value is used for anything.

So you need to add some logic in the else-branch to decide whether to set the speed to the crouch speed or to the walk speed.

```
    if (isGrounded == false)
    {
        Speed = AirSpeed;
    }
    else
    {
        if (isCrouching) {
            Speed = CrouchSpeed; 
        } 
        else 
        {
            Speed = WalkSpeed; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This works and is the fastest solution to get them going. I recommend, however, considering having things like "in the air" and "crouching" being flags that modify the overall velocity of the character. This will let you have a walk speed, crouch speed, air speed, and crouching air speed. It's harder to work out the formula but knocks out some if-else branches that can get really hairy really fast if you're not careful.